# How can I run a software package I installed called 'openscam'?

Tags: installation, command-line, software-center, launcher

I installed a software called 'openscam' but I cannot find its launcher.

It's installer is a .deb file, after I clicked in it, Ubuntu Software Center installed the software, and finished it, but I cannot find its launcher.

I tried to reinstall it, the same problem.
I tried to install it from terminal, but it says, "openscam is aldready the newest version".
I installed all package dependencies.

I searched the launcher in /usr/bin and /usr/share/applications but I didn't find anything.

I'm using 12.04 LTS.

Software's site is http://openscam.com/

Please help if you can!

Comment: what happens if you execute 'openscam' in terminal?

Comment: Yeah, I suspect that it simply doesn't have a launcher icon. Just press `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `T` and type in `openscam` and press enter. If that works, then in future you can load it by simply pressing `Ctrl` + `F2` and typing in `openscam`.

This will work with any other package, just replace `openscam` with the package name.

Answer (score 3):

In a terminal, install the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtkglext1 libc6 bzip2 zlib1g libexpat1 openssl libgtk2.0-0 libglade2-0 freeglut3 sqlite3
```

Then type `openscam` in the terminal to open it up.

*Source: [OpenSCAM Install Guide](http://openscam.com/wiki/InstallGuide). Though I've added the package* `libgtkglext1` *because it also needs it.*

Comment: OMG That was so fast! Thank u so much Alaa! //Eldian

Comment: Welcome to the Linux community =). When you're able to, mark my answer as your accepted answer so that others searching for this issue can easily find it.

Comment: Great.  I've added libgtkglext1 to the OpenSCAM Install Guide.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of OpenSCAM.  I've just release a new version which includes a build for Precise Penguin 64-bit and has improved instructions for building from source.

If you have ANY problems with this software please create a ticket on the GitHub page:

https://github.com/CauldronDevelopmentLLC/OpenSCAM/issues

Or email me.

NOTE, OpenSCAM is now called CAMotics.